# Parse impersonate user

Tags: parse-platform

I need to debug some user issues which can only be debugged by actually being the user. Is there a way I can impersonate a user without knowing their password? I'd rather not have to reset their password in the DB as that will lose the original one.

Comment: Can you get their session token? Obviously the preference is to duplicate the issue with a new account, perhaps by exporting the data and importing to your dev account

Comment: @Wain How would I get their session token? Make an endpoint people can go to, to let me steal it? Sounds scary. Should I be storing it in the DB on login anyways?